# How to quickly select loops by skipping line by line

Tags: selection-tools, select

[image: sel]
I want to jump loop one by one as the GIF shows and select the loop.
But this is repetitive and boring.
Do you know how to do this type of work quickly in Blender?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you, depending on your topology:

[image]

1. Select 2 edges at the right interval
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> (repeatedly), expand the selection at the same interval.
3. Header > Select menu, *Select Loops* > *Edge Loops*